# Iterate through object of object array and serach a value

Tags: angular

In my angular 7 application, I am trying to loop through an array of objects and return true if it finds any of the HurdleRate set to true or else return false. It neednt iterate further if it finds first true value

The AllTerms object contains an array of LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel and LegalFundClassSideLetterViewModel.

I am trying to loop through the object but noticed that it is not iterating through the entire object collection. Could somebody point out the right way to do it

Code

```
  checkVisibility() {
        let columnCheck: boolean = true;
        for (var i = 0; i < this.LegalFundClasses.AllTerms.length; i++) {
          if (this.LegalFundClasses.AllTerms[i].LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel.HurdleRate === false) {
            return false;
          }
        }
        return columnCheck;
      }
```

JSON

```
[{"LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel":{"Description":"Class A (Soft Closed)","AuditSummary":"dmukerji Apr 26, 2019","FeesReviewSummary":"dmukerji Apr 26, 2019","TermsReviewSummary":"dmukerji Nov 29, 2018","ChildRecordExist":true,"Id":10651,"FundId":3640,"FundClassType":1,"CurrencyId":3,"PrimaryCurrencyName":"EUR","OtherCurrencyIds":[{"Id":2,"Name":"Test"}],"OtherCurrencyNames":["USD"],"ManagerStrategyId":null,"ManagerStrategyName":null,"SubVotingId":2,"SubVotingName":"Yes","SubHotIssueId":4,"SubHotIssueName":"No Capital","RedsFrqncyId":11,"RedsFrqncyName":"3rd Anniversary","RedsNoticeDays":90,"NoticeTypeOfDaysId":2,"NoticeTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","RedemptionComments":null,"LockupTypeId":1,"LockupTypeName":"Rolling","HardDurationMonthsId":null,"HardDurationMonthsName":null,"SoftDurationMonthsId":8,"SoftDurationMonthsName":"36","LockupFees0To12Pct":0,"LockupFees12To24Pct":0,"LockupFees24To36Pct":0,"WebfolioRedsFee":null,"LockupComments":"Following the expiration of the initial Class A Shares lockup, absent a redemption or exchange of such Class A Shares, such Shares will be subject to a new Class A Shares lock-up which will immediately commence on a rolling basis, in each case ending on the redemption day falling in the month of the three-year anniversary of the commencement of such Class A Shares lock up. Class A Shares may be redeemed on the first redemption days falling on the expiration of each New Class A shares lock up without being subject to a redemption fee. Special Redemption Rights where shareholder is permitted to redeem up to 5% of their holding of Shares. See key fund disclosures.                                                                                                    * Investors can redeem upto 5% of their holding at the first anniversary date and thereafter an additional 5% on one of the four redemption dates falling on- January, April, July or October during each 12 month period (i.e year 2 and year 3 of investment). No redemption penalties are applicable. ","ApplyGateDecliningBalance":false,"GateInvestorPct":0,"GateSourceId":1,"GateSourceName":"Fund Gate","GateFundClassPct":50,"IntialProceeds":95,"PaymentInDays":14,"PaymentTypeOfDaysId":1,"PaymentTypeOfDaysName":"Business","HoldbackPercentage":5,"HoldbackPayment":30,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysId":2,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","ManagementFeeRate":1.5,"IncentiveFeeRate":18,"RealizationFrequencyId":22,"RealizationFrequencyName":"Every third anniversary","HighWaterMarkId":1,"HighWaterMarkName":"Standard","HurdleRate":false,"HurdleRateBasisId":null,"HurdleRateBasisName":null,"HurdleRatePct":null,"HurdleRateIndexId":null,"HurdleRateIndexName":null,"PreferredReturnRatePct":null,"GpCatchUp":null,"PreferredReturnComments":null,"Clawback":false,"ClawbackPercentage":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeId":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeName":null,"FeeComments":"The incentive fee is payable at the end of the investor lock-up period. \n","FeeReductionsNegotiated":null,"InvestmentStatusId":1,"LegalParentClassId":null},"LegalFundClassSideLetterViewModel":null},{"LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel":{"Description":"Class B (Soft-Closed)","AuditSummary":"dmukerji Mar 11, 2019","FeesReviewSummary":"dmukerji Mar 11, 2019","TermsReviewSummary":"dmukerji Nov 29, 2018","ChildRecordExist":true,"Id":10656,"FundId":3640,"FundClassType":1,"CurrencyId":3,"PrimaryCurrencyName":"EUR","OtherCurrencyIds":[{"Id":2,"Name":"Test"}],"OtherCurrencyNames":["USD"],"ManagerStrategyId":null,"ManagerStrategyName":null,"SubVotingId":2,"SubVotingName":"Yes","SubHotIssueId":4,"SubHotIssueName":"No Capital","RedsFrqncyId":10,"RedsFrqncyName":"2nd Anniversary","RedsNoticeDays":90,"NoticeTypeOfDaysId":2,"NoticeTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","RedemptionComments":null,"LockupTypeId":1,"LockupTypeName":"Rolling","HardDurationMonthsId":null,"HardDurationMonthsName":null,"SoftDurationMonthsId":7,"SoftDurationMonthsName":"24","LockupFees0To12Pct":0,"LockupFees12To24Pct":0,"LockupFees24To36Pct":4,"WebfolioRedsFee":null,"LockupComments":"Class B Shares may first be redeemed on redemption day falling in the month of the two-year anniversary of the issue of Class B Shares. In the event that a shareholder requests redemption of Class B Shares on the first redemption day falling on the expiration of the initial Class B Shares, the Fund will charge a redemption fee of 4.00% of the redemption proceeds. Following the expiration of Class B lock-up, absent a redemption or exchange of such Class B Shares, such Shares will be subject to a new Class B lock up which will immediately commence on a rolling basis, in each case ending on the redemption day falling in the month of the two year anniversary of the commencement of such Class B lock-up. Class B may be redeemed on the redemption day failing on the expiration of each New Class B lock-up without being subject to a redemption fee. Special Redemption Rights where shareholder is permitted to redeem up to 5% of their holding of Shares. See key fund disclosures. ","ApplyGateDecliningBalance":false,"GateInvestorPct":0,"GateSourceId":1,"GateSourceName":"Fund Gate","GateFundClassPct":50,"IntialProceeds":95,"PaymentInDays":14,"PaymentTypeOfDaysId":1,"PaymentTypeOfDaysName":"Business","HoldbackPercentage":5,"HoldbackPayment":30,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysId":2,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","ManagementFeeRate":1.75,"IncentiveFeeRate":20,"RealizationFrequencyId":21,"RealizationFrequencyName":"Every second anniversary ","HighWaterMarkId":1,"HighWaterMarkName":"Standard","HurdleRate":false,"HurdleRateBasisId":null,"HurdleRateBasisName":null,"HurdleRatePct":null,"HurdleRateIndexId":null,"HurdleRateIndexName":null,"PreferredReturnRatePct":null,"GpCatchUp":null,"PreferredReturnComments":null,"Clawback":false,"ClawbackPercentage":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeId":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeName":null,"FeeComments":"The incentive fee is payable at the end of the investor lock-up period. \n","FeeReductionsNegotiated":null,"InvestmentStatusId":1,"LegalParentClassId":null},"LegalFundClassSideLetterViewModel":null},{"LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel":{"Description":"Class C (Soft Closed)","AuditSummary":"dmukerji Apr 26, 2019","FeesReviewSummary":"dmukerji Apr 26, 2019","TermsReviewSummary":"","ChildRecordExist":true,"Id":10658,"FundId":3640,"FundClassType":1,"CurrencyId":3,"PrimaryCurrencyName":"EUR","OtherCurrencyIds":[{"Id":2,"Name":"Test"}],"OtherCurrencyNames":["USD"],"ManagerStrategyId":null,"ManagerStrategyName":null,"SubVotingId":2,"SubVotingName":"Yes","SubHotIssueId":4,"SubHotIssueName":"No Capital","RedsFrqncyId":9,"RedsFrqncyName":"Anniversary","RedsNoticeDays":90,"NoticeTypeOfDaysId":2,"NoticeTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","RedemptionComments":null,"LockupTypeId":1,"LockupTypeName":"Rolling","HardDurationMonthsId":null,"HardDurationMonthsName":null,"SoftDurationMonthsId":5,"SoftDurationMonthsName":"12","LockupFees0To12Pct":6,"LockupFees12To24Pct":4,"LockupFees24To36Pct":null,"WebfolioRedsFee":"12 M,0.06|24 M,0.04|","LockupComments":"Class C Shares may first be redeemed on the redemption day falling in the month of the one-year anniversary of the issue of such shares. In the event the shareholder requests redemption of Class C Shares falling on the expiration of the initial Class C lock-up, the Fund will charge a redemption fee of 6% of the redemption proceeds. Following the expiration of the initial Class C lock-up, absent a redemption or exchange of such Class C Shares, such shares will be subject to a new Class C lock-up which will immediately commence on a rolling basis, in each case ending on the redemption day falling in the month of the anniversary of the commencement of such Class C lock-up. If Class C Shares are redeemed on the redemption day falling on the expiration of the first new Class C lock-up, the Fund will charge a redemption fee of 4% of the redemption proceeds. If Class C Shares are redeemed on the first redemption day falling on the expiration of the second new Class C Shares lock-up or any subsequent new Class C lock-up such Shares may be redeemed without a redemption fee. Special Redemption Rights where shareholder is permitted to redeem up to 5% of their holding of Shares. See key fund disclosures. ","ApplyGateDecliningBalance":false,"GateInvestorPct":0,"GateSourceId":1,"GateSourceName":"Fund Gate","GateFundClassPct":50,"IntialProceeds":95,"PaymentInDays":14,"PaymentTypeOfDaysId":1,"PaymentTypeOfDaysName":"Business","HoldbackPercentage":5,"HoldbackPayment":30,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysId":2,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","ManagementFeeRate":2,"IncentiveFeeRate":22,"RealizationFrequencyId":7,"RealizationFrequencyName":"Yearly","HighWaterMarkId":1,"HighWaterMarkName":"Standard","HurdleRate":false,"HurdleRateBasisId":null,"HurdleRateBasisName":null,"HurdleRatePct":null,"HurdleRateIndexId":null,"HurdleRateIndexName":null,"PreferredReturnRatePct":null,"GpCatchUp":null,"PreferredReturnComments":null,"Clawback":false,"ClawbackPercentage":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeId":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeName":null,"FeeComments":"The incentive fee is payable at the end of the investor lock-up.","FeeReductionsNegotiated":null,"InvestmentStatusId":1,"LegalParentClassId":null},"LegalFundClassSideLetterViewModel":null},{"LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel":{"Description":"Class C Interests (Soft Closed)","AuditSummary":"rmenon Jun 21, 2019","FeesReviewSummary":"","TermsReviewSummary":"","ChildRecordExist":true,"Id":11812,"FundId":7069,"FundClassType":1,"CurrencyId":2,"PrimaryCurrencyName":"USD","OtherCurrencyIds":[{"Id":3,"Name":"Test"}],"OtherCurrencyNames":["EUR"],"ManagerStrategyId":null,"ManagerStrategyName":null,"SubVotingId":3,"SubVotingName":"No","SubHotIssueId":2,"SubHotIssueName":"Investor Discretion","RedsFrqncyId":9,"RedsFrqncyName":"Anniversary","RedsNoticeDays":90,"NoticeTypeOfDaysId":2,"NoticeTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","RedemptionComments":null,"LockupTypeId":1,"LockupTypeName":"Rolling","HardDurationMonthsId":null,"HardDurationMonthsName":null,"SoftDurationMonthsId":5,"SoftDurationMonthsName":"12","LockupFees0To12Pct":6,"LockupFees12To24Pct":4,"LockupFees24To36Pct":null,"WebfolioRedsFee":"12 M,0.06|24 M,0.04|","LockupComments":"In the event that a Limited Partner requests withdrawal of a Class C Capital Account on the Withdrawal Date falling on the expiration of the Initial Class C Lock-Up, the Partnership will retain an amount equal to 6 per cent of the withdrawal proceeds. Following the expiry of the Initial Class C Lock-Up, absent a withdrawal or exchange of such Class C Capital Account, such Class C Capital Account will be subject to a new Class C Lock-Up which will immediately commence on a rolling basis ending on the Withdrawal Date falling in the month of the anniversary of the commencement of such Initial Class C Lock-Up (each, a \"New Class C Lock-Up\"). If a Class C Capital Account is withdrawn on the Withdrawal Date falling on the expiration of the first New Class C Lock-Up, the Partnership will retain an amount equal to 4 per cent of the withdrawal proceeds. If a Class C Capital Account is withdrawn on the Withdrawal Date falling on the expiration of the second New Class C Lock-Up or any subsequent New Class C Lock-Up, such Capital Account may be withdrawn without being subject to a withdrawal charge.","ApplyGateDecliningBalance":false,"GateInvestorPct":0,"GateSourceId":1,"GateSourceName":"Fund Gate","GateFundClassPct":50,"IntialProceeds":95,"PaymentInDays":14,"PaymentTypeOfDaysId":1,"PaymentTypeOfDaysName":"Business","HoldbackPercentage":5,"HoldbackPayment":30,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysId":2,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","ManagementFeeRate":2,"IncentiveFeeRate":22,"RealizationFrequencyId":7,"RealizationFrequencyName":"Yearly","HighWaterMarkId":1,"HighWaterMarkName":"Standard","HurdleRate":true,"HurdleRateBasisId":null,"HurdleRateBasisName":null,"HurdleRatePct":null,"HurdleRateIndexId":null,"HurdleRateIndexName":null,"PreferredReturnRatePct":null,"GpCatchUp":null,"PreferredReturnComments":null,"Clawback":true,"ClawbackPercentage":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeId":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeName":null,"FeeComments":"The incentive fee is payable at the end of the investor lock-up period. \n","FeeReductionsNegotiated":null,"InvestmentStatusId":1,"LegalParentClassId":null},"LegalFundClassSideLetterViewModel":null},{"LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel":{"Description":"Class A Interests (Soft Closed)","AuditSummary":"dmukerji Apr 26, 2019","FeesReviewSummary":"dmukerji Apr 26, 2019","TermsReviewSummary":"dmukerji Nov 29, 2018","ChildRecordExist":true,"Id":11815,"FundId":7069,"FundClassType":1,"CurrencyId":2,"PrimaryCurrencyName":"USD","OtherCurrencyIds":[{"Id":3,"Name":"Test"}],"OtherCurrencyNames":["EUR"],"ManagerStrategyId":null,"ManagerStrategyName":null,"SubVotingId":3,"SubVotingName":"No","SubHotIssueId":2,"SubHotIssueName":"Investor Discretion","RedsFrqncyId":11,"RedsFrqncyName":"3rd Anniversary","RedsNoticeDays":90,"NoticeTypeOfDaysId":2,"NoticeTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","RedemptionComments":null,"LockupTypeId":1,"LockupTypeName":"Rolling","HardDurationMonthsId":null,"HardDurationMonthsName":null,"SoftDurationMonthsId":8,"SoftDurationMonthsName":"36","LockupFees0To12Pct":0,"LockupFees12To24Pct":0,"LockupFees24To36Pct":0,"WebfolioRedsFee":null,"LockupComments":" Following the expiration of the initial Class A Shares lockup, absent a redemption or exchange of such Class A Shares, such Shares will be subject to a new Class A Shares lock-up which will immediately commence on a rolling basis, in each case ending on the redemption day falling in the month of the three-year anniversary of the commencement of such Class A Shares lock up. Class A Shares may be redeemed on the first redemption days falling on the expiration of each New Class A shares lock up without being subject to a redemption fee. Special Redemption Rights where shareholder is permitted to redeem up to 5% of their holding of Shares. See key fund disclosures.                                                                                                    * Investors can redeem upto 5% of their holding at the first anniversary date and thereafter an additional 5% on one of the four redemption dates falling on- January, April, July or October during each 12 month period (i.e year 2 and year 3 of investment). No redemption penalties are applicable. ","ApplyGateDecliningBalance":false,"GateInvestorPct":0,"GateSourceId":1,"GateSourceName":"Fund Gate","GateFundClassPct":50,"IntialProceeds":100,"PaymentInDays":14,"PaymentTypeOfDaysId":1,"PaymentTypeOfDaysName":"Business","HoldbackPercentage":5,"HoldbackPayment":30,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysId":2,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","ManagementFeeRate":1.5,"IncentiveFeeRate":18,"RealizationFrequencyId":22,"RealizationFrequencyName":"Every third anniversary","HighWaterMarkId":1,"HighWaterMarkName":"Standard","HurdleRate":false,"HurdleRateBasisId":null,"HurdleRateBasisName":null,"HurdleRatePct":null,"HurdleRateIndexId":null,"HurdleRateIndexName":null,"PreferredReturnRatePct":null,"GpCatchUp":null,"PreferredReturnComments":null,"Clawback":false,"ClawbackPercentage":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeId":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeName":null,"FeeComments":"The incentive fee is payable at the end of the investor lock-up period. \n","FeeReductionsNegotiated":null,"InvestmentStatusId":1,"LegalParentClassId":null},"LegalFundClassSideLetterViewModel":null}]
```

Comment: do you want to know at least one of `HurdleRate: false` exists?

Comment: No. I just want to know atleast one Hurdle rate true exist. If not return false

Comment: All the LegalFundClassSideLetterViewModel are null (checked the JSON with Notepad++). Could that be the reason why not all objects are iterated?

Comment: Think about accepting one of the answers and if these did not satisfy you please stay in the loop and indicate what you are still missing.

Answer (score 0):

Off course it is not iterating through the entire object collection because when the first false(y) item is encountered your implementation returns false...

Also `this.LegalFundClasses.AllTerms[i].LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel.HurdleRate`
is incorrect as we inspect the JSON you provided. `LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel` is a class type of item(s) in the collection not a property of an item in the collection.

May I propose to do it this way:

```
checkVisibility() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.LegalFundClasses.AllTerms.length; i++) {
        const term = this.LegalFundClasses.AllTerms[i];

        if (term && term.HurdleRate === true) {

            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Go through the `AllTerms` collection and immediately return true when the first item that has `HurdleRate` set to true is encountered. Otherwise, when the complete collection is iterated but a return has not been executed, false is returned. Just as per your request ***"return true if it finds any of the HurdleRate set to true or else return false"***

You could also use [some][1].

```
checkVisibility() {
  return this.LegalFundClasses.AllTerms.some(term => term && term.HurdleRate === true)
}
```

Comment: I need to check in both the objects ie.LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel and  LegalFundClassSideLetterViewModel . My code checks only one.

Comment: Are these objects side-by-side existing in the AllTerms collection? And do you know for sure that both are available by the AllTerms property?

Comment: The allterms contain both these objects. Sometimes LegalFundClassSideLetterViewModel  could be null but LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel  will always have some values

Comment: But when the iteration enounters a null reference it will "crash". See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const obj = [{"LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel":{"Description":"Class A (Soft Closed)","AuditSummary":"dmukerji Apr 26, 2019","FeesReviewSummary":"dmukerji Apr 26, 2019","TermsReviewSummary":"dmukerji Nov 29, 2018","ChildRecordExist":true,"Id":10651,"FundId":3640,"FundClassType":1,"CurrencyId":3,"PrimaryCurrencyName":"EUR","OtherCurrencyIds":[{"Id":2,"Name":"Test"}],"OtherCurrencyNames":["USD"],"ManagerStrategyId":null,"ManagerStrategyName":null,"SubVotingId":2,"SubVotingName":"Yes","SubHotIssueId":4,"SubHotIssueName":"No Capital","RedsFrqncyId":11,"RedsFrqncyName":"3rd Anniversary","RedsNoticeDays":90,"NoticeTypeOfDaysId":2,"NoticeTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","RedemptionComments":null,"LockupTypeId":1,"LockupTypeName":"Rolling","HardDurationMonthsId":null,"HardDurationMonthsName":null,"SoftDurationMonthsId":8,"SoftDurationMonthsName":"36","LockupFees0To12Pct":0,"LockupFees12To24Pct":0,"LockupFees24To36Pct":0,"WebfolioRedsFee":null,"LockupComments":"Following the expiration of the initial Class A Shares lockup, absent a redemption or exchange of such Class A Shares, such Shares will be subject to a new Class A Shares lock-up which will immediately commence on a rolling basis, in each case ending on the redemption day falling in the month of the three-year anniversary of the commencement of such Class A Shares lock up. Class A Shares may be redeemed on the first redemption days falling on the expiration of each New Class A shares lock up without being subject to a redemption fee. Special Redemption Rights where shareholder is permitted to redeem up to 5% of their holding of Shares. See key fund disclosures.                                                                                                    * Investors can redeem upto 5% of their holding at the first anniversary date and thereafter an additional 5% on one of the four redemption dates falling on- January, April, July or October during each 12 month period (i.e year 2 and year 3 of investment). No redemption penalties are applicable. ","ApplyGateDecliningBalance":false,"GateInvestorPct":0,"GateSourceId":1,"GateSourceName":"Fund Gate","GateFundClassPct":50,"IntialProceeds":95,"PaymentInDays":14,"PaymentTypeOfDaysId":1,"PaymentTypeOfDaysName":"Business","HoldbackPercentage":5,"HoldbackPayment":30,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysId":2,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","ManagementFeeRate":1.5,"IncentiveFeeRate":18,"RealizationFrequencyId":22,"RealizationFrequencyName":"Every third anniversary","HighWaterMarkId":1,"HighWaterMarkName":"Standard","HurdleRate":false,"HurdleRateBasisId":null,"HurdleRateBasisName":null,"HurdleRatePct":null,"HurdleRateIndexId":null,"HurdleRateIndexName":null,"PreferredReturnRatePct":null,"GpCatchUp":null,"PreferredReturnComments":null,"Clawback":false,"ClawbackPercentage":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeId":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeName":null,"FeeComments":"The incentive fee is payable at the end of the investor lock-up period. \n","FeeReductionsNegotiated":null,"InvestmentStatusId":1,"LegalParentClassId":null},"LegalFundClassSideLetterViewModel":null},{"LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel":{"Description":"Class B (Soft-Closed)","AuditSummary":"dmukerji Mar 11, 2019","FeesReviewSummary":"dmukerji Mar 11, 2019","TermsReviewSummary":"dmukerji Nov 29, 2018","ChildRecordExist":true,"Id":10656,"FundId":3640,"FundClassType":1,"CurrencyId":3,"PrimaryCurrencyName":"EUR","OtherCurrencyIds":[{"Id":2,"Name":"Test"}],"OtherCurrencyNames":["USD"],"ManagerStrategyId":null,"ManagerStrategyName":null,"SubVotingId":2,"SubVotingName":"Yes","SubHotIssueId":4,"SubHotIssueName":"No Capital","RedsFrqncyId":10,"RedsFrqncyName":"2nd Anniversary","RedsNoticeDays":90,"NoticeTypeOfDaysId":2,"NoticeTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","RedemptionComments":null,"LockupTypeId":1,"LockupTypeName":"Rolling","HardDurationMonthsId":null,"HardDurationMonthsName":null,"SoftDurationMonthsId":7,"SoftDurationMonthsName":"24","LockupFees0To12Pct":0,"LockupFees12To24Pct":0,"LockupFees24To36Pct":4,"WebfolioRedsFee":null,"LockupComments":"Class B Shares may first be redeemed on redemption day falling in the month of the two-year anniversary of the issue of Class B Shares. In the event that a shareholder requests redemption of Class B Shares on the first redemption day falling on the expiration of the initial Class B Shares, the Fund will charge a redemption fee of 4.00% of the redemption proceeds. Following the expiration of Class B lock-up, absent a redemption or exchange of such Class B Shares, such Shares will be subject to a new Class B lock up which will immediately commence on a rolling basis, in each case ending on the redemption day falling in the month of the two year anniversary of the commencement of such Class B lock-up. Class B may be redeemed on the redemption day failing on the expiration of each New Class B lock-up without being subject to a redemption fee. Special Redemption Rights where shareholder is permitted to redeem up to 5% of their holding of Shares. See key fund disclosures. ","ApplyGateDecliningBalance":false,"GateInvestorPct":0,"GateSourceId":1,"GateSourceName":"Fund Gate","GateFundClassPct":50,"IntialProceeds":95,"PaymentInDays":14,"PaymentTypeOfDaysId":1,"PaymentTypeOfDaysName":"Business","HoldbackPercentage":5,"HoldbackPayment":30,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysId":2,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","ManagementFeeRate":1.75,"IncentiveFeeRate":20,"RealizationFrequencyId":21,"RealizationFrequencyName":"Every second anniversary ","HighWaterMarkId":1,"HighWaterMarkName":"Standard","HurdleRate":false,"HurdleRateBasisId":null,"HurdleRateBasisName":null,"HurdleRatePct":null,"HurdleRateIndexId":null,"HurdleRateIndexName":null,"PreferredReturnRatePct":null,"GpCatchUp":null,"PreferredReturnComments":null,"Clawback":false,"ClawbackPercentage":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeId":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeName":null,"FeeComments":"The incentive fee is payable at the end of the investor lock-up period. \n","FeeReductionsNegotiated":null,"InvestmentStatusId":1,"LegalParentClassId":null},"LegalFundClassSideLetterViewModel":null},{"LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel":{"Description":"Class C (Soft Closed)","AuditSummary":"dmukerji Apr 26, 2019","FeesReviewSummary":"dmukerji Apr 26, 2019","TermsReviewSummary":"","ChildRecordExist":true,"Id":10658,"FundId":3640,"FundClassType":1,"CurrencyId":3,"PrimaryCurrencyName":"EUR","OtherCurrencyIds":[{"Id":2,"Name":"Test"}],"OtherCurrencyNames":["USD"],"ManagerStrategyId":null,"ManagerStrategyName":null,"SubVotingId":2,"SubVotingName":"Yes","SubHotIssueId":4,"SubHotIssueName":"No Capital","RedsFrqncyId":9,"RedsFrqncyName":"Anniversary","RedsNoticeDays":90,"NoticeTypeOfDaysId":2,"NoticeTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","RedemptionComments":null,"LockupTypeId":1,"LockupTypeName":"Rolling","HardDurationMonthsId":null,"HardDurationMonthsName":null,"SoftDurationMonthsId":5,"SoftDurationMonthsName":"12","LockupFees0To12Pct":6,"LockupFees12To24Pct":4,"LockupFees24To36Pct":null,"WebfolioRedsFee":"12 M,0.06|24 M,0.04|","LockupComments":"Class C Shares may first be redeemed on the redemption day falling in the month of the one-year anniversary of the issue of such shares. In the event the shareholder requests redemption of Class C Shares falling on the expiration of the initial Class C lock-up, the Fund will charge a redemption fee of 6% of the redemption proceeds. Following the expiration of the initial Class C lock-up, absent a redemption or exchange of such Class C Shares, such shares will be subject to a new Class C lock-up which will immediately commence on a rolling basis, in each case ending on the redemption day falling in the month of the anniversary of the commencement of such Class C lock-up. If Class C Shares are redeemed on the redemption day falling on the expiration of the first new Class C lock-up, the Fund will charge a redemption fee of 4% of the redemption proceeds. If Class C Shares are redeemed on the first redemption day falling on the expiration of the second new Class C Shares lock-up or any subsequent new Class C lock-up such Shares may be redeemed without a redemption fee. Special Redemption Rights where shareholder is permitted to redeem up to 5% of their holding of Shares. See key fund disclosures. ","ApplyGateDecliningBalance":false,"GateInvestorPct":0,"GateSourceId":1,"GateSourceName":"Fund Gate","GateFundClassPct":50,"IntialProceeds":95,"PaymentInDays":14,"PaymentTypeOfDaysId":1,"PaymentTypeOfDaysName":"Business","HoldbackPercentage":5,"HoldbackPayment":30,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysId":2,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","ManagementFeeRate":2,"IncentiveFeeRate":22,"RealizationFrequencyId":7,"RealizationFrequencyName":"Yearly","HighWaterMarkId":1,"HighWaterMarkName":"Standard","HurdleRate":false,"HurdleRateBasisId":null,"HurdleRateBasisName":null,"HurdleRatePct":null,"HurdleRateIndexId":null,"HurdleRateIndexName":null,"PreferredReturnRatePct":null,"GpCatchUp":null,"PreferredReturnComments":null,"Clawback":false,"ClawbackPercentage":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeId":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeName":null,"FeeComments":"The incentive fee is payable at the end of the investor lock-up.","FeeReductionsNegotiated":null,"InvestmentStatusId":1,"LegalParentClassId":null},"LegalFundClassSideLetterViewModel":null},{"LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel":{"Description":"Class C Interests (Soft Closed)","AuditSummary":"rmenon Jun 21, 2019","FeesReviewSummary":"","TermsReviewSummary":"","ChildRecordExist":true,"Id":11812,"FundId":7069,"FundClassType":1,"CurrencyId":2,"PrimaryCurrencyName":"USD","OtherCurrencyIds":[{"Id":3,"Name":"Test"}],"OtherCurrencyNames":["EUR"],"ManagerStrategyId":null,"ManagerStrategyName":null,"SubVotingId":3,"SubVotingName":"No","SubHotIssueId":2,"SubHotIssueName":"Investor Discretion","RedsFrqncyId":9,"RedsFrqncyName":"Anniversary","RedsNoticeDays":90,"NoticeTypeOfDaysId":2,"NoticeTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","RedemptionComments":null,"LockupTypeId":1,"LockupTypeName":"Rolling","HardDurationMonthsId":null,"HardDurationMonthsName":null,"SoftDurationMonthsId":5,"SoftDurationMonthsName":"12","LockupFees0To12Pct":6,"LockupFees12To24Pct":4,"LockupFees24To36Pct":null,"WebfolioRedsFee":"12 M,0.06|24 M,0.04|","LockupComments":"In the event that a Limited Partner requests withdrawal of a Class C Capital Account on the Withdrawal Date falling on the expiration of the Initial Class C Lock-Up, the Partnership will retain an amount equal to 6 per cent of the withdrawal proceeds. Following the expiry of the Initial Class C Lock-Up, absent a withdrawal or exchange of such Class C Capital Account, such Class C Capital Account will be subject to a new Class C Lock-Up which will immediately commence on a rolling basis ending on the Withdrawal Date falling in the month of the anniversary of the commencement of such Initial Class C Lock-Up (each, a \"New Class C Lock-Up\"). If a Class C Capital Account is withdrawn on the Withdrawal Date falling on the expiration of the first New Class C Lock-Up, the Partnership will retain an amount equal to 4 per cent of the withdrawal proceeds. If a Class C Capital Account is withdrawn on the Withdrawal Date falling on the expiration of the second New Class C Lock-Up or any subsequent New Class C Lock-Up, such Capital Account may be withdrawn without being subject to a withdrawal charge.","ApplyGateDecliningBalance":false,"GateInvestorPct":0,"GateSourceId":1,"GateSourceName":"Fund Gate","GateFundClassPct":50,"IntialProceeds":95,"PaymentInDays":14,"PaymentTypeOfDaysId":1,"PaymentTypeOfDaysName":"Business","HoldbackPercentage":5,"HoldbackPayment":30,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysId":2,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","ManagementFeeRate":2,"IncentiveFeeRate":22,"RealizationFrequencyId":7,"RealizationFrequencyName":"Yearly","HighWaterMarkId":1,"HighWaterMarkName":"Standard","HurdleRate":true,"HurdleRateBasisId":null,"HurdleRateBasisName":null,"HurdleRatePct":null,"HurdleRateIndexId":null,"HurdleRateIndexName":null,"PreferredReturnRatePct":null,"GpCatchUp":null,"PreferredReturnComments":null,"Clawback":true,"ClawbackPercentage":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeId":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeName":null,"FeeComments":"The incentive fee is payable at the end of the investor lock-up period. \n","FeeReductionsNegotiated":null,"InvestmentStatusId":1,"LegalParentClassId":null},"LegalFundClassSideLetterViewModel":null},{"LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel":{"Description":"Class A Interests (Soft Closed)","AuditSummary":"dmukerji Apr 26, 2019","FeesReviewSummary":"dmukerji Apr 26, 2019","TermsReviewSummary":"dmukerji Nov 29, 2018","ChildRecordExist":true,"Id":11815,"FundId":7069,"FundClassType":1,"CurrencyId":2,"PrimaryCurrencyName":"USD","OtherCurrencyIds":[{"Id":3,"Name":"Test"}],"OtherCurrencyNames":["EUR"],"ManagerStrategyId":null,"ManagerStrategyName":null,"SubVotingId":3,"SubVotingName":"No","SubHotIssueId":2,"SubHotIssueName":"Investor Discretion","RedsFrqncyId":11,"RedsFrqncyName":"3rd Anniversary","RedsNoticeDays":90,"NoticeTypeOfDaysId":2,"NoticeTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","RedemptionComments":null,"LockupTypeId":1,"LockupTypeName":"Rolling","HardDurationMonthsId":null,"HardDurationMonthsName":null,"SoftDurationMonthsId":8,"SoftDurationMonthsName":"36","LockupFees0To12Pct":0,"LockupFees12To24Pct":0,"LockupFees24To36Pct":0,"WebfolioRedsFee":null,"LockupComments":" Following the expiration of the initial Class A Shares lockup, absent a redemption or exchange of such Class A Shares, such Shares will be subject to a new Class A Shares lock-up which will immediately commence on a rolling basis, in each case ending on the redemption day falling in the month of the three-year anniversary of the commencement of such Class A Shares lock up. Class A Shares may be redeemed on the first redemption days falling on the expiration of each New Class A shares lock up without being subject to a redemption fee. Special Redemption Rights where shareholder is permitted to redeem up to 5% of their holding of Shares. See key fund disclosures.                                                                                                    * Investors can redeem upto 5% of their holding at the first anniversary date and thereafter an additional 5% on one of the four redemption dates falling on- January, April, July or October during each 12 month period (i.e year 2 and year 3 of investment). No redemption penalties are applicable. ","ApplyGateDecliningBalance":false,"GateInvestorPct":0,"GateSourceId":1,"GateSourceName":"Fund Gate","GateFundClassPct":50,"IntialProceeds":100,"PaymentInDays":14,"PaymentTypeOfDaysId":1,"PaymentTypeOfDaysName":"Business","HoldbackPercentage":5,"HoldbackPayment":30,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysId":2,"HoldbackTypeOfDaysName":"Calendar","ManagementFeeRate":1.5,"IncentiveFeeRate":18,"RealizationFrequencyId":22,"RealizationFrequencyName":"Every third anniversary","HighWaterMarkId":1,"HighWaterMarkName":"Standard","HurdleRate":false,"HurdleRateBasisId":null,"HurdleRateBasisName":null,"HurdleRatePct":null,"HurdleRateIndexId":null,"HurdleRateIndexName":null,"PreferredReturnRatePct":null,"GpCatchUp":null,"PreferredReturnComments":null,"Clawback":false,"ClawbackPercentage":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeId":null,"AssetFeeDiscountTypeName":null,"FeeComments":"The incentive fee is payable at the end of the investor lock-up period. \n","FeeReductionsNegotiated":null,"InvestmentStatusId":1,"LegalParentClassId":null},"LegalFundClassSideLetterViewModel":null}]

for(let o of obj) {
      let LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel = o['LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel'];

      let LegalFundClassSideLetterViewModel = o['LegalFundClassSideLetterViewModel'];

     if(check(LegalFundClassSideLetterViewModel) === true || check(LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel) === true){ 
        return true
     }



}


check(obj) {
    for(let prop in obj){
       if(prop == "HurdleRate" && obj[prop] === true) {
           return true
       }
    }
```

Comment: I need to check in both the objects ie.LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel and  LegalFundClassSideLetterViewModel . My code checks only one.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for something like this?

```
if(typeof(this.LegalFundClasses.AllTerms.find(item => item.LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel.HurdleRate === true)) === 'undefined'){
      console.log("nothing found");
    } else {
      console.log("found true value");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that you are immediately returning `false` as soon as the `HurdleRate` for one of the elements in your array is found to be false. The right way to do this would be something like this.

```
checkVisibility() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.LegalFundClasses.AllTerms.length; i++) {
      if ((this.LegalFundClasses.AllTerms[i].LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel || this.LegalFundClasses.AllTerms[i].LegalFundClassSideLetterViewModel).HurdleRate) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This code could be further simplified using the `find` method like this. What the code does is that it finds the element where `HurdleRate` is true and the function returns `true` if there's any element matching the condition and `false` if there's no element matching the condition.

```
checkVisibility() {    
    return !!terms.find((term) => {
        return (term.LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel || term.LegalFundClassSideLetterViewModel).HurdleRate;
    });
}
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: I need to check in both the objects ie.LegalFundClassCommercialViewModel and  LegalFundClassSideLetterViewModel . My code checks only one.

Comment: @Tom I have edited my answer accordingly. Hope this works.

Comment: Though the second one looks simpler it would iterate through all the elements and return value each time right

Comment: @Tom If it finds an array element where the function returns a true value, `find()` returns the value of that array element (and does not check the remaining values).

Comment: In your first solution why is it always showing i = 0 in this.LegalFundClasses.AllTerms[i]. Doesnt seem to be looping

Comment: I haven't actually tested it using the first solution. Seems like there was an error in the first solution. I have modified. Hope this helps.